# Vue.js: mutually exclusive child component state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a set of dynamic children:

Parent
 child1
 child2
 ...
 childn

I want to capture the onclick event on a child, and make a couple dom changes (expand a div, change icon), then ensure the other children have the opposite changes (ie, the div is collapsed and the icon is the closed icon).

What is the best vue-style way of accomplishing this?

I know how to emit events from the children up to the parent, and how to attach properties to the children, just not sure how to use those to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that I handle these is to use an `activeIndex` to track which one is open.

on the emit listeners, you update the the `activeIndex`.

then in your teomplate you can use `<child isOpen="activeIndex===3"/>`

you can get a bit more complicated and scalable/reusable, but this is *probably* enough for your needs. If you can post some code, I can update with more relevant example.

Comment: Do you emit event from children and handle on parent and then update prop on children, or just send a global event bus message?

Comment: That's the vue way, props down and events up. For children, you can use `computed` values or `watch` to react to changes. I don't use a custom bus, if I need to have a global state, I use vuex.